# How do you hedge volatility risk?

Tags: volatility, stochastic-processes, hedging, stochastic-volatility, best-practices

Suppose I model an asset $S_1(t)$ under a stochastic volatility model. To price an option on $S_1$, I must assume the existence of an asset $S_2$ that is used to hedge against changes in the volatility of $S_1$.

I suspect that, under reasonable models of market prices, no such asset exists. Are there any assets that come close? How do big hedge funds hedge against changes in volatility?

Comment: I wanted to include this in the OP, but it is really a separate question: I read a while ago that you can calculate a "price of volatility-risk" using utility functions. I have been unable to find this formula again, but is this something that is actually done **in practice**?

Comment: Estimating the _equity_ risk premium from utility functions is contentious enough. I doubt this approach is widely used in practice for the variance risk premium. [Coval and Shumway (2001, JF)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/0022-1082.00352) infer price of variance risk from returns of beta-hedged ATM straddles. [Carr and Wu (2009, RFS)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/22/3/1311/1581057) estimate the price of variance risk from returns of variance swaps.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. To start with what are $S_1$ and $S_2$? Base assets or derivatives on the same underlier?

Comment: @frido-rolloos: Suppose I model an asset S1(t) under a stochastic volatility model. To price [derivatives on this] asset, I must assume the existence of an asset S2(t) that is used to hedge [volatility changes in S1]. Suppose S1 = S&P 500 index, then what is S2? What is its ticker symbol ?

Comment: @noob2 So if the question of the OP is what asset does one need to hedge the vol risk of other options, isn't the answer that the required (hedge) asset is another option? I'm stil confused what the question then is.

Comment: noob2 's edits were correct. I suppose I wrote the OP too last last night. @FridoRolloos if the answer is "another option", what option? What if S1 = AT&T? What "another option" could I trade in theory and what "other options" are traded in practice? Are there any books that go into detail?

Comment: Does this question and answer help: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58521/hedging-in-the-heston-model